# Testrail Java API: Unable to attach report to testrun

Tags: java, api, rest-assured, testrail

API endpoint:

[POST] https:///{{testrail link}}/index.php?/api/v2/add_attachment_to_run/449

Headers: { "Content-Type","value":"multipart/form-data" }

In body I am passing Key : attachment and value: path of file.
PFA screenshot of the same.

The error right now on Postman : { "error": "No file attached or upload size was exceeded." }

The upload size is just fine (under 256 MB)[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `attachment` to type **File**, not Text.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Able to attach file now.